# I would like to be able to edit a .txt file with

Tags: batch-file, logging, cmd, silent

I need to just write text the last line on a specific text file each time the batch file is ran. So,

Run cmd

writes "test" just below the last line that was written to the .txt file.

The purpose is to create a log file that will just say that the cmd I'm trying run ran. That's it. I'm also hoping to make this silent.

I've found instructions to find a specific string of text and replace it, but as I said I want all pervious data to remain in the file.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "append text to a file." Try googling that.

Comment: `Echo test >File.txt`

Comment: and if you run that command from a batch-file you can use the character @ as the first char in the line to make it silent `@echo test >File.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The only line you need in the batch file that you run is

```
@echo test >>your_logfile_name
```

Where `test` can be virtually any text and `your_logfile_name` can be any valid filename.

Note that `>>` will **append** to the file whereas `>` as you have been misadvised will **replace** any existing file content with the test line.

Comment: you are so right with that `>>` append feature.  I should have noticed that.  Sorry @Josh for my misadvice.  But let me ask you:  what does the `#`-char in front of `echo`?

Comment: @loco : it's actually a `@` - typo.

Comment: What do you mean typo? I `#echo` all the time

Comment: You're good you both were really helpful and I appreciate it. I knew it would be something simple like that, but after an hour on the googlesphere I couldn't anything that simple. Or at least I didn't recognize it. I actually think I saw this while searching and just didn't get it. Now that I'm thinking about it. I'm brilliant that way. Like looking for my sunglasses that are on my face. Thanks again you gents are brilliant.